# What should be in my /etc/fstab if I have two discs?

Tags: freebsd, fstab, swap

I have a laptop. It has two hard drives. One is an SSD with a normal Windows 10 install on it. The other is an mSata with a normal install of FreeBSD13 on it.

To install FreeBSD I removed the SSD, booted from the FreeBSD installer on a USB stick, installed FreeBSD to the mSata using the auto options, then shut down my machine and put the SSD back in.

When I look at gpart show it says this:

```
=>       63  468862065  ada0  MBR  (224G)
         63       1985        - free -  (993K)
       2048    1124352     1  ntfs  [active]  (549M)
    1126400  466549872     2  ntfs  (222G)
  467676272        912        - free -  (456K)
  467677184    1179648     3  !39  (576M)
  468856832       5296        - free -  (2.6M)

=>       40  250069600  ada1  GPT  (119G)
         40       1024     1  freebsd-boot  (512K)
       1064        984        - free -  (492K)
       2048    4194304     2  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
    4196352  245872640     3  freebsd-zfs  (117G)
  250068992        648        - free -  (324K)
```

I believe this is telling me that ada0 is my Windows 10 disc, and that ada1 is my FreeBSD disk.

When I look in /etc/fstab I see this line (there are no other entries).

```
/dev/ada0p2             none    swap    sw              0       0
```

Did my method of installing FreeBSD cause an error? Is this something I need to fix? How should I fix it - what should my /etc/fstab actually say?

I'm guessing it should say /dev/ada1p2.

Comment: @Hannu thank you Hannu. The machine boots fine by using the bios boot option key, which launches the bios boot selection menu, which then boots either Win10 or FreeBSD. This is a normal method of dualbooting FreeBSD. Grub is deprecated for FreeBSD. https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/grub2

Comment: On your GPT-partitioned disk currently known as /dev/ada1, you should assign GPT labels to each of the partitions, and then your /etc/fstab should reference those partitions by their GPT labels, **not** by raw /dev/adaXpY devices.  That's what GPT labels are for.  Unless and until you get that sorted, yes, your fstab on /dev/ada1 needs to reference partitions on /dev/ada1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing it should say /dev/ada1p2.

You surmise correctly.  So long as that particular disk is plugged into that particular controller slot (all other things being equal), your system will probably see it as `ada1`.  So yes, your swap partition on `ada1` is correctly referenced as `ada1p2`.

But if you ever change your disk configuration, the device number may change, and then your `/etc/fstab` may break.  Since you have a GPT partition on `ada1`, a better practice is to apply a GPT label to the swap partition:

```
# gpart modify -l bsd-swap -i 2 /dev/ada1
```

and then mount it in /etc/fstab using the partition **name** (which is fixed) instead of the device/partition *number* (which is variable):

```
/dev/gpt/bsd-swap    none    swap    sw       0       0
```